# Does "הֵאָסְפוּ" signify unity as the key to redemption?

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, messianic-redemption

The [verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.49.1?lang=bi&with=all) says וַיִּקְרָא יַעֲקֹב אֶל־בָּנָיו וַיֹּאמֶר הֵאָסְפוּ וְאַגִּידָה לָכֶם אֵת אֲשֶׁר־יִקְרָא אֶתְכֶם בְּאַחֲרִית הַיָּמִים׃, And Jacob called his sons and said, “Come together that I may tell you what is to befall you in days to come.

Is there a source or commentary that suggests Jacob is conveying to his children that when they הֵאָסְפוּ - unite, the revelation of *Geulah*/ *Mashiach* will occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sfas Emes (Vayechi 5638)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefat_Emet%2C_Genesis%2C_Vayechi.8.3?lang=he) says something along these lines:

> לכן בש"ק שזוכין לנחלת יעקב בלי מצרים מתעורר קצת גאולה. וכתיב האספו ואגידה. הקבצו ושמעו כו' שע"י התאחדות והתכללות כ"א מתעורר כוחו של יעקב. וזה ג"כ הטעם בשבת דמתאחדין ברזא דאחד לכן מתעורר כוחו כנ"ל. וחכמים הגידו כי ביקש לגלות הקץ ונסתם ממנו כו'. בודאי הי' חסרון שלא היו יכולין להתאחד כמו שהי' רצון יעקב. וכפי מציאות האחדות כן מתעורר ומתגלה הקץ כנ"ל.
>
> Therefore, on the holy Shabbos, when we merit the boundless inheritance of Yaakov, some of the Geulah is aroused. It says "assemble and I will tell you... gather and listen...," since through unity and interconnection, Yaakov's power is aroused. This is also why on Shabbos, when the spiritual forces "unite in the mystery of One," his power is aroused, as above. The Sages tell us that he wanted to reveal the Ketz but it was concealed from him... Surely there was something missing, that they couldn't unite the way Yaakov wanted to. **The more unity exists, the more the Ketz is aroused and revealed,** as above.